# Finishing a Workflow Activity gives "An item with the same key has already been added" error

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have setup a very simple approval workflow for a certain type of content. However, for some reason, the first manual activity couldn't be finished and thus, workflow being blocked.

Any attempt to finish the activity will prompt this error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
Unable to finish the Workflow Activity (tcm:x-xxxxx-xxxxxx)
```

Here's the data I'm working with (truncated for readability):

```xml
<Content xmlns="uuid:fac33fb4-7b36-465a-af40-f3b80c4f3f65">
    <contactlist>
        <name>Lorem ipsum dolor</name>
        <address>sit amet consectetur</address>
        <photo xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
               xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-80196" 
               xlink:title="photo-1"></photo>
        <email>email1@email.com</email>
        <phone>interdu eget</phone>
        <mailimage xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                   xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-80195" 
                   xlink:title="email-icon"></mailimage>
    </contactlist>
    <contactlist>
        <name>Lorem ipsum dolor</name>
        <address>sit amet consectetur</address>
        <photo xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
               xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-80197" 
               xlink:title="photo-2"></photo>
        <email>email@email.com</email>
        <phone>interdu eget</phone>
        <mailimage xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                   xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-80195" 
                   xlink:title="email-icon"></mailimage>
    </contactlist>
</Content>
```

Notice that I am reusing the same email-icon image for *[mailImage]* attribute. I'm inclined to think that this is causing the error because it's the only duplicated component link in the list.

If I remove the mail image component links and finish the activity, it works and I can proceed with the workflow. Odd huh?

I don't see any reason why I can't reuse component links in the same component in regard of workflows being able to proceed. I mean, CMS allowed me to save the component, why not allow me to proceed with Workflow?

EDIT: By the way, this is the error from the Event Logs:

```
Unable to finish the Workflow Activity (tcm:5-18430-131104)
An item with the same key has already been added.

Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)

Call stack:
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey,TValue,Boolean)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey,TValue)
Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.ActivityInstance.SaveBinariesAndGetBinaryIds(String,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.ActivityInstance.OnFinishing(FinishActivityEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.ActivityInstance.Finish(ActivityFinish)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.Workflow.ActivityInstanceFacade.FinishActivity(UserContext,String,String,String,String,String,String)
ActivityInstance.FinishActivity
```

Comment: Do you have auditing turned on? It's the property on process definition called "Track changes between activitities", or StoreSnapshot?

Comment: Yes, I remember ticking that checkbox when I first saved the process definition from Visio.

Comment: I had the same error for a different scenario. See resolution on Tridion Stack Exchange (http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2454/46). In my case it was code trying to add a Process Instance Variable with an already existing key. This question and answer helped rule out the Process Definition Properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

THe problem you have is because of your auditing template. It might be the case that you have old (pre 2011) VBScript template as your auditing template. Try switching auditing off, or change auditing templates values in properties of your publication

Comment: You may be right. May I know how can auditing be turned off? I can't seem to find the property from Visio or from the CMS.

Comment: You may be right. May I know how can auditing be turned off? I can't seem to find the property from Visio or from the CMS. The publication properties doesn't seem to have anything related with turning off auditing... 

This is the first time I heard about auditing templates. I have yet to learn how it works.

Comment: Double click the Start shape and choose Process Definition Properties from the pop-up menu, then in the Auditing field you can disable "Track changes between Activity steps", see also the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_47_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8) (login required)

Comment: That was it! I'll check out the link you gave me. I need to know how we can leverage that in our current setup. I only checked that assuming it will give more info in the logs should we need it. (But I'll read about it later... have to sleep! :p) Thanks so much!